# jquery load a section of a page without loading images of other sections

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery .load function to pull data from an external php file which contains some data about each item,
When you click on an item, the section related to that item gets loaded but since the whole content is in one single php , it loads everything on that page including images first, then it shows the requested section and this makes it take too long for the first item,

Is there any way to load a section and not images of other sections?

```
$('#ContentHolder').load('content.php #section',function(){
Do Something
)};
```

Comment: Yes, load the html using $.ajax or $.get and use regexp or string manipulation to get only the part of the htmlstring you want without parsing the rest.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for your answer, could you please give me an example? each section has an Id that's why I Used hash, now in this method how should I specify that ID?

Comment: No, not exactly. Parsing html with a regexp or string manipulation is pretty involved. too much for a comment, and i don't really have a full answer to share at the moment. You wouldn't really be able to specify an ID because you'll be working directly with a string, not an html structure.

Comment: You could use a regexp to replace all occurences of `src=` with `data-src=`, parse the string into an html structure, filter down to just your section, then update the `src` attribute of all elements with a `data-src` attribute to the value of `data-src`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load part of a page using the hash symbol? That won't work... what might work is something like this, if you don't know or want to know RegEx - try this - inspired by others' comments:

```
    $.get('content.php', function(data) {
        var repData = data.replace('src', 'data-src');
        var parsedData = $(repData).parseHTML();           
        var extractData = $(parsedData).children('div#mySection').html();

        $('#ContentHolder').html(extractData);
    });
```